# xargs into different files

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs

I have a bash 'for loop' that does what I want

```
for i in *.data
do
    ./prog $i >dir/$i.bck
done
```

Can I turn this into an xargs construct ?
I've tried something like

```
ls *.data|xargs -n1  -I FILE ./prog FILE >dir/FILE.bck
```

But I have problems with the FILE rightside of '>'

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try (you can use `FILE` instead of `%` if you prefer):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.data' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I % sh -c './prog % > dir/%.bck'
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ is designed for this kind of tasks:

```
ls *.data | parallel ./prog {} '>'dir/{}.bck
```

IMHO this is more readable than the xargs solution provided.

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ